# Activity restarts when switching between virtual and physical keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity restarts when I change the "use physical keyboard" from the status bar and vice versa. I have looked at many solutions on web and SA. They generally suggest changing the manifest file as follows;

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

and adding the following code to the activity;

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

However, none helped me. My application still restarts, i.e. all the `EditText` values are reset and selected values in `Spinners` are reset. What further can I do to prevent my activity restarting o keyboard source change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in an activity tag in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

and use onConfigChanges without setContentView

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
     // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: You are Welcome Faruk :)